# What is the meaning of the equestrian term “Undermounted”?

Tags: meaning, terminology

In a literary research effort to study the written testimonial of British Cavalry officer Louis Edward Nolan (1818-1854), we have difficulties in translating into Swedish a single word, as he in 1852 describes Swedish horses as

> rather undermounted.

Is there perhaps anyone here that could assist us?

Answer (score 9):

*Undermounted* is used to describe a cavalry's horses as not being as strong and sturdy as other cavalries’ horses.

Here is an example:

> *20th March, Morár.*—Out at an early hour to the review of the 16th Irregular Cavalry , a fine corps and of grand *physique*, but somewhat
> undermounted, I thought. At least the horses should be as good as the
> men in a cavalry regiment, if not (as some prefer) better. Long
> jack-boots hanging down the sides of under-sized nags do not
> prepossess.
>  <sub>[Some Records of Crime—Being the Diary of a Year,
> Official and Particular, of an Officer of the Thuggee and Dacoitie
> Police · Volume
> 1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Some_Records_of_Crime/iok9AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22undermounted%22+%22cavalry%22&pg=PA375&printsec=frontcover) by Charles Hervey, 1892</sub>

In this article about the selective breeding of Australian stock horses, the author notes:

> Despite the mixed origins of these horses, they developed into a
> strong and handsome type which was eventually called the Waler. . . .
> The hardiness of the Waler made him a natural mount for the cavalry
> and when the British found themselves undermounted at the time of the
> Indian Mutiny, the Waler came to the rescue.
>  <sub>[Australian
> Stock
> Horse—History](https://www.hiddentrails.com/general/breeds/australian_stock_horse.htm)</sub>

Comment: In the following article “undermounted” seems to refer to the rider rather than the horse. “*I firmly believe that a rider must be undermounted in order to enjoy success. In other words, your horse should be too easy for you to handle. He should be the right size and shape and temperament for you.*” https://books.google.it/books?id=oog8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT152&dq=%22undermounted%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5u9GqyZn8AhWjR_EDHfY3CewQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22undermounted%22&f=false

Comment: Great find! I've posted my answer as an addition only and your answer is the one the OP is looking for as it was the sense of the term _undermounted_ used in the past. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition: In modern equine terminology, *undermounted* defines a rider who is riding a horse too small for them, as opposed to *overmounted* which defines a rider who is riding a horse too big for them. There are various factors at play and *[Horse Illustrated](https://www.horseillustrated.com/horse-training-mount-suitability-matching-horse-to-rider)* summarizes as below:

> Generally, the ideal “leg length” requires that the rider’s stirrup lay (about) three-quarters of the way down between the horse’s topline and base of girth. If the stirrup lies much lower than this, the rider may appear too tall for the horse (**undermounted**); if the stirrup lies much higher, the rider may appear too small (**overmounted**). Somewhere between the two are several inches of “happy medium” where the overall picture of horse and rider is ideal. But this can’t be used as an ironclad rule, because there are additional considerations.

Here is another reference from *[Introduction to Equestrian Sports](https://books.google.ca/books?id=q2IeT_GXPVkC&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=%22undermounted%22%20horse&source=bl&ots=n9C-bZl9qv&sig=ACfU3U1MNn7BJolddpbWHeOkFCW4rUzmug&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD9IKL4Jn8AhWeRvEDHeIVDlMQ6AF6BAhREAM#v=onepage&q=%22undermounted%22%20&f=false)*
(edited by Kate Luxmoore):

> The horse's height should be viewed as rungs on a ladder, for children. Horses are not school shoes. You cannot buy a horse a couple of sizes too big so that the child will grow into it. Moving a child from a 13.2hh pony to a 16hh horse is a massive jump which may make the child frightened and reluctant to ride. A child is better off being undermounted (riding a horse which is too small) and safe and happy, than overmounted (riding a horse which is too large) and frightened.